# Set a File Etag in web.config

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service, web-config

Using an Apache Server you can set a file etag in the .htaccess file as follows

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg)$">
FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>
```

This is useful to stop browser caching of an image file.

Is there an equivalent setting that can be put in a web.config file?
My site is running on an Azure App Service

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Apache Server, are you trying to disable cache for specific name extension files? if so, you can try below steps:

Open IIS -> output caching ->add –> put the name extension such as .jpg–> set prevent all caching on both user-mode and kernel mode. You can add more rules for .png  .jpeg etc.

[image]

Also these are what the web.config looks like:

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching>
        <profiles>
            <add extension=".jpg" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
        </profiles>
    </caching>
</system.webServer>
```

If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about etag.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try this on my website running in Azure App Service. but didn't seem to work. I did notice that the server is actually kestrel. Perhaps this doesn't support this option.